# Many very similar updates to an SQL table - optimization?

Tags: mysql, c

I have a C function as follows, which takes a connection from elsewhere, and performs a (potentially very large) number of (very similar) insertions into a particular table. This code also includes `glib.h`, `my_global.h`, `assert.h` and `mysql.h` (but that isn't relevant here). The code is below:

```
char* MAKE_TABLE_CMD = "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE graph (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, weight INT NOT NULL);";

char* ADD_ROW_CMD = "INSERT INTO graph (weight) VALUES (0);";

gboolean graph_make (MYSQL* conn_ptr, guint64 size) {
  assert(conn_ptr);
  if (!mysql_query(conn_ptr, MAKE_TABLE_CMD)) {
    gboolean loop_successful = TRUE;
    for (guint64 i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      if (mysql_query(conn_ptr, ADD_ROW_CMD)) {
        loop_successful = FALSE;
        break;
      }
    }
    return loop_successful;
  } else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

When I tried this with even remotely large enough values to warrant using a database table (10,000 rows), it took this end of forever. Based on my profiling, this function is the bottleneck, and I'm guessing that all those `ADD_ROW_CMD`s are the problem. Is there any way I can optimize this, given the inherent similarity of the rows?

Disclaimer: I'm a complete SQL noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab a block of records to insert in one pass like so:

```
insert into graph (weight) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
```

Depending on how many records you have to insert you can process 1000 (for example) records with each query instead of build query -> insert -> acknowledge -> repeat;

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use multiple values in one insert-query like @Wranorn said, and there is always only one client accessing your database at a time, you may try to disable the autocommit and foreign-key checks before those large insertions and re-enable it afterwards.

```sql
SET autocommit = 0; --execute this in the beginning
SET foreign_key_checks=0;

--execute the insertions
--..

SET autocommit = 1; --execute this in the end
SET foreign_key_checks=1;
```

Comment: Can your and @Wranorn's approaches be combined?

Comment: yes they can, however the result wouldn't be significant if you've already modified your query into like what Wranorn suggested; since you'd only have one single insert statement.